# How to "install" a python program?

Tags: python

this is a pretty basic question but I'm not really finding any answer, maybe my keywords are wrong...

I've been programming in Python for a little while now and I made a few scripts that are good enough to be deployed in the department where I am working. So... Am I going to have to make everyone install Python on their machines, and then go through the tedium to install all the modules I use in the scripts with pip, or is there a better solution? Obviously I have zero experience with this, so far I've only been working on Visual Studio and running my scripts from there. I would appreciate a couple pointers, the topic is very broad and I feel lost.

Comment: Google py2exe or to whatever platform. **Google is your friend**

Comment: I used a mixture of [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python official docs have a lot of info about this.

For 3.x.x [Setup script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html)

For 2.7.x [Built dist](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to create a module, as if it's intended for pip, that you do not publish on PyPI, but allow people to install locally.

For example, observe this project on GitHub: [pyjokes](https://github.com/pyjokes/pyjokes). It's available on PyPI so you can pip install it. But you can also download the repo and install from source. This would install it as if you'd installed it using pip (because pip is just a wrapper for "download this project and run the installer").

The procedure for installing this project from source would be:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyjokes/pyjokes
cd pyjokes
sudo python3 setup.py install  # python 3
sudo python setup.py install  # python 2
```

Take a look at the way the project is laid out. The essentials are the setup.py file and the `__init__.py` in the `pyjokes` folder. That should be enough to make your project installable locally.

Then you can distribute the code (perhaps a private github or bitbucket repository), and use the README to describe the installation instructions.

Note: I've described a Linux installation process, but I'm fairly sure it works the same on Mac too. I'm not sure about Windows.